# Referring to VARs on other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a site.

Currently, the site asks you for your name on the front page, and saves your name in a string variable.

```
var name="";
```

After they enter their name and click "Enter Site" it goes to a new page. On this new page I want it to say "Hello 'NAME' .. blahblah".

Is there a way to save the var name so other files recognize it from the main.html.

Someone previously recommended saving it in cookies, but will this work if my site isn't online (its only .html files, not currently part of a domain).

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Using cookies or local storage is your best bet, when using javascript. When using php you can use sessions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Cookies or `localStorage`: that is the only way.

Comment: HTML files could include JavaScript files and javascript can set a cookie.

Comment: No, I'm  not using PHP.

How would I go about using localstorage or cookies to save this particular variable?

Comment: Why did you tag php if you aren't using it?

Comment: I dunno, on a tagging spree I suppose.

Comment: Then please be more careful and considerate about tags from now on.

Comment: You could also append the value as a query string param (or a hash value) and extract it on the other page with JavaScript. Though you would have to deal with the potential of XSS

Comment: If you are only passing name, you can pass it with query string or hash value: 'mypage.html?name=MyName' or 'mypage.html#myName' and catch those on your other page.

Comment: The code I have currently has "/name=*NAME*" at the end of the url/location after you press the button to enter the site, how do I retrieve it from the other page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookie for this. There is not another way to transfer variable between pages if you are not using database or something.

For this you can use simple jQuery plugin [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to make easy calls:

**Create the cookie**

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

**Read the cookie:**

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
```

and you can do this on every page you need in the host.

---

***edited***

and of course [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) also.

Comment: If my current webpage also states the variable in its location/url, is there a way to retrieve it from there, for example its something like: "www.test.com?name=Jordan". || Also for your codes, can you make some additional comments as to what I can edit to personalize it, I dont know what { expires: 7, ... } and all that is. Sorry, I'm still learning a few of the basics.

Comment: To get username from URL you need to do GET function with some backend language (PHP, Ruby, Node.js etc). But if you want to use only JS you can parse url using hashtags like this: domain.com/#/John. I'll make some fiddle for you.

Comment: Expires is amount of days what means how many days it will be saved in clients browser. path is for set cookie on each page you need, for example "/" means that you can do that on your domain, which is global and can reach from any sub pages in your site.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ErAdONUj/1#test depend on this fiddle it will give you "test" or anything what you type after # in the url. source code is here: http://jsbin.com/ErAdONUj/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try using javascript to set and get cookie values.

```
     function getCookie(c_name)
       {
        var c_value = document.cookie;
        var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
        if (c_start == -1)
           {
           c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
           }
        if (c_start == -1)
           {
           c_value = null;
           }
       else
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
          var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
          if (c_end == -1)
          {
         c_end = c_value.length;
           }
         c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
           }
         return c_value;
            }

          function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
           {
          var exdate=new Date();
          exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
          var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";                   expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
          document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
          }

          function checkCookie()
           {
           var username=getCookie("username");
          if (username!=null && username!="")
             {
            document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML="Welcome " + username;

             }
          else 
             {
             username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
          if (username!=null && username!="")
             {
            setCookie("username",username,365);
             }
           }
        }
    </script>
```